# TypeScript to compile to both commonjs and umd

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to have a tsconfig such that I can create both commonjs and umd output such that I end up getting

```
src/
  files.ts
lib/
  umd.js
dist/
  files.js
```

Comment: You could create 2 tsconfig files!

Comment: You can also override this setting on the command line `tsc --project ./tsconfig.json --module umd`

Answer (score 1):

No, Typescript doesn't support simultaneous compiler modules. You can however create multiple tsconfig.json files:

- tsconfig.json (for development, etc.)
- umd.tsc.json
- commonjs.tsc.json (it can be named anything as long as it's a valid json tsconfig.)

Configure those as you need and then call them to achieve the same effect. You can add a build script, whatever you like.

package.json

```
{
...
  "scripts": {
...
    "build:both": "tsc -p path/to/umd.tsc.json && tsc -p path/to/commonjs.tsc.json"
  }
}
```

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#using-tsconfigjson)
[Github Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2867#issuecomment-204528633)

Comment: One would typically use the `"extends"` option to share configuration in such a setup.